# How to get table data based on id which obtains from another table data? Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-datatable

#### Views

```py
company = Company.objects.get(id = company_id)  # getting input from django urls (<int:company_id>)
vehicles = CompanyContainVehicles.objects.filter(company_id=company.id)  # Give all rows having same id (company.id)
all_vehicles = Vehicles.objects.filter(id=vehicles.vehicle_id)  # Not Working
```

How do I get data from tables whose multiple id's obtained by another table?

#### Models

```py
class Company(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()

class Vehicles(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    vehicle_number = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)


class CompanyContainVehicles(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    company_id = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vehicle_id = models.ForeignKey(Vehicles, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

Above are my table details and I need to get all vehicles from table Vehicles which is obtained from CompanyContainVehicle table (that define which company seel out which vehicle) based on company_id that obtain from table Company which contains details of companies.

Comment: Do you want all the data including it's related child table data?

Comment: Yes, I need child table data also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
Vehicles.objects.filter(companycontainvehicles__company_id=company_id)
```

Here your `companycontainvehicles` basically acts as a `ManyToManyField`. You can span a many-to-many relation between `Vehicle` and `Company` with:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    vehicle_number = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    companies = models.ManyToManyField(
        Company,
        through='CompanyVehicle',
        related_name='companies'
    )

class CompanyVehicle(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Then you can filter with:

```
Vehicle.objects.filter(companies=company_id)
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Vehicle` instead of <s>`Vehicles`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `company`, instead of <s>`company_id`</s>.